# Problem when trying to connect to my EC2 instance on Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Since 2 hours, I'm trying to connect on my EC2 instance on AWS but I'm getting this error

There was a problem setting up the instance connection
Log in failed. If this instance has just started up, try again in a minute or two.

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Is your instance in default vpc? What are your security groups?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are seeing the instance running. You can check the system logs using "Action--> Instance Settings --> Get System Log" See anything suspicious making the instance unhealthy ? Also check the instance metrics (Monitoring) to see if any CPU/Disk is spiking ?

would not hurt to do a STOP and START. I have had experience where STOP and START helped instead of the reboot.

Its hard to diagnose without additional information.

Also you may refer to
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html